# Match and capture the (capital) letters inside the square brackets

Tags: regex, capture, square-bracket

I'm fairly new to regex and I'd like to know the pattern to match and capture the letters inside the square brackets. For example, I'd like to capture DATA from the string below. My sample code's as below:

```
var myString = "testing/node/234 test_TEST [1234] testing [DATA] SUMMARY,VALUES,abcd,1,0,0";
var re = new RegExp("\[([A-Z]+)\]");
var match = re.exec(myString);
console.log(match[1]);
```

It's giving me a syntax error: * Unmatched ')' * at the second line.

Comment: You will need to escape square brackets.

Comment: by _MATCH AND CAPTURE THE (CAPITAL) LETTERS_ do you mean if the input is `[DATA123asdHI]`, then it should capture `DATAHI` or the whole string inside the square bracket is in capital letters and you want to select that.

Comment: I'd like it to match and capture only if all the characters inside the square brackets are capital letters. e.g., DATA in [DATA], no match if [DATAabcd], and no match if [data]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how similar the tested strings are and how strict you want your regex, you have multiple choices from less strict to more strict:

1. Simply match something between square brackets:

   ```
   \[(.+)\]
   ```

   You will probably want a non-greedy regex, in this case. Because if there were 2 different things between brackets e.g. `[AB] some text [CD]` it would capture `AB] some text [CD`. The non-greedy flag will prevent this.
2. match square brackets after closing parenthesis and space:

   ```
   \)\s\[(.+)\]
   ```
3. match the square brackets after exactly 3 words:

   ```
   (?:[^\s]+\s){3}\[(.+)\]
   ```

You can still go stricter depending on your needs, but you get the point.

**Stricter regex** will prevent accidentally matching something you didn't expect. For example if `test_module` would have been `[test_module]` the first regex would have matched that, the other two would not have.

This is particularly important when the string is completely or even partially composed by user input. Never trust the user ;)

Answer (score 4):

Try using:

```
\[([A-Z]+)\]
```

To capture the brackets with capital letters only.

Two match two or more strings into the brackets, use `/g` for global selection.

Comment: `var re = new RegExp("\[([A-Z]+)\]");`
That gives me a syntax error saying "Unmatched ')'  "

Answer (score 0):

The "best" way in my opinion would be a look behind and a lookahead

```
(?<=\[)[A-Z]+?(?=\])
```

**This will avoid selecting the brackets also**

Or perhaps:

```
\[([A-Z]+?)\]
```

in a more limited flavor